# Что нужно знать о кроссбраузерности верстальщику?

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

Здравствуйте. Не могу найти в интернете основные методы по кроссбраузерности.
Ну я видел пару раз, что для некоторых стилей в css прописывают кроссбраузерность, но чёткого списка не нашел. Надо просто заучить оперделенные стили или есть какой-то общий профил?

Так же хотел бы спросить это нормально что в brackets после переписки css с сайта *autoprefixer*

отображает красным *-webkit-box-pack* и *-webkit-box-pack*?

```css
.menu{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите https://caniuse.com, если не встречали. Для CSS часть рутины с кроссбраузерностью может взять [автопрефиксер](https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/).

Comment: Также есть таблицы поддержки функций [ECMAScript 5](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) и [ECMAScript 6](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) разными движками JavaScript.

Comment: @Андрей, можете пожалуйста ещё посмотреть вопрос я дополнил его

Comment: Да, нормально все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верстальщику для написания рабочей вёрстки под несколько браузеров потребуется:

1. Каталог CSS свойств и их поддержка разными браузерами, для примера можно воспользоваться вот этим [сборником от MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Reference).
2. Аналогичный каталог для JS методов, пример [там](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Methods_Index) же.